# Generic AsyncTask with Error Handling and progress dialog

Tags: android, generics, android-asynctask, handlers

please tell me best way to write this.

I need one generic AsyncTask for webservice call with all possible errror handling. Also a callback for updating UI/ showing error message.

I have found few approches :

1. by adding Generic  parameter to async task
2. making asynctask as abstract
3. for handling error giving handler object.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very easy to do with an `AsyncTask`.

`AsyncTask` has 4 functions. 3 of them run on the UI Thread so you can update the UI as much as you like. 1 of the functions runs in the background so you can do things that take as long as is necessary, such as calling your webservice.

You do not need a formal callback function. `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` handles this for you.

There is a great [example in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that shows how to download a file exactly as you are trying to do with the webservices connection. You will `extend AsyncTask` and create your own `DownloadFilesTask` just like in the example.

The whole thing is started with a single line of code:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(...)
```

The four functions are:

- [onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) - Useful for displaying a `ProgressBar` or other
  UI elements.
- [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) - Take as long as you want, but don't update
  the UI from here. Instead, call `publishProgress()` as often as you
  like. That will internally call `onProgressUpdate()` where you can
  incrementally update the UI, or your `ProgressBar`, if you want.
- [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) - Optional show progress updates or increment
  a `ProgressBar`. This function only gets called in response to calling 
  `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()`.
- [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) - Done, `dismiss()` your `ProgressBar`, update
  the UI, process any errors saved in `doInBackground()`, and jump to 
  the next section of your code.

**Error Handling**:

All errors are trapped in `doInBackground()`. You should save an `int errorCode` and/or `String errorMessage` in your `DownloadFilesTask` class, and `return;` from `doInBackground()` when an error occurs. Then, process and report the error in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: please suggest approches. To hadle it generically for any request, response, exception

Comment: Thanks for all your help; I have already done same thing. but I need a better modular sacalable approch.

Comment: Make your `DownloadFilesTask` into a separate class (i.e. in another Java file) pass in URL and the like, and it returns a `String`, XML Object, JSON, whatever via access functions. Also provide `getErrorCode()` and `getErrorMessage()`. I understand that this is probably not the exact modular puzzle piece that you are looking for to build a reusable component, but it is all that can be done from the limited text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133003/how-to-handle-asynctask-failure) for several answers. They all involve storing any exception thrown by `doInBackground` in a field and checking it in `onPostExecute`. I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139173/2212420)  posted by @dongshengcn, which encapsulates this into a subclass of `AsyncTask`, then you can override `onResult` and/or `onException` as necessary.