# Can not send email to Gmail using JavaMail API

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I encountered some problems while sending an email to Gmail email ID which I am using in my application.

I am using `JavaMail Api` to send the email.

When I press the button "Send", a Toast message  "Sending success" is displayed, in `onPostExecute` method, but  no new email is sent to Gmail ID,that I am using in program.

I need help !

My code below:

```
public class GmailSender extends Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new android.readnews.support.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GmailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
            String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0) {
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            } else {
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            }
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
public class SendEmailFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    Context mContext = null;
    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
    EditText edtYourEmail, edtSubjectEmail, edtBodyEmail;
    final String myEmail = "abc@gmail.com";
    final String myPass = "abcxyz";
    String yourEmail = "";
    String Subject = "";
    String BodyEmail = "";
    GmailSender sender;

    public SendEmailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendemail_layout, container,
                false);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        ImageButton btnSendMail = (ImageButton) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        edtYourEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MailFromBox);
        edtSubjectEmail = (EditText) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
        edtBodyEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
        btnSendMail.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        yourEmail = edtYourEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        Subject = edtSubjectEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        BodyEmail = edtBodyEmail.getText().toString();  
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Sending Mail...", true);

        SendMail sendmailTask = new SendMail();
        sendmailTask.execute();
    }



class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                sender = new GmailSender(myEmail, myPass);
                sender.sendMail(Subject, BodyEmail, myEmail, yourEmail);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("abc ", "abc " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result == true) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                edtYourEmail.setText("");
                edtSubjectEmail.setText("");
                edtBodyEmail.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sending success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sending failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at android.readnews.support.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:67)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at android.readnews.main.SendEmailFragment$SendMail.doInBackground(SendEmailFragment.java:93)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at android.readnews.main.SendEmailFragment$SendMail.doInBackground(SendEmailFragment.java:1)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-13 15:35:15.697: W/System.err(1394):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-13 15:35:15.733: W/InputMethodManagerService(397): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@53787d20 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@5375079c
01-13 15:40:25.134: W/ThrottleService(397): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log? It's not strange that you get a "sending success" message, since you catch and swallow all exceptions in the `doInBackground` method. Or at least return a non-null result in the try block to see whether it actually succeeded.

Comment: @Zoltán i update above

Comment: For a quick solution, print the message of the exception (e.g. `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`) to quickly find out why authentication failed, but I suggest you to implement error handling as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133284/900130

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need all the [socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), start by cleaning up that and your other [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  You don't need your own [ByteArrayDataSource since it's included with JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).  Then, follow these [Gmail instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) and [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  You might need to [enable support for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).  [OAuth2 support](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) might also be helpful.